# Regarding the use of filter()

Tags: python

Ive been studying the built-in-functions for python for a while now, im trying to have a firm grasp of ideal situations to apply them for later. Ive understood all of them except filter(), the arguments being `filter(function, iterable)`. In docs.python.org it states:

> If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

I decided to work off of that since I didn't grasp what function was asking(obviously, it needs a function;however, what kind?)This is what tried:

```
a=filter(None,[1,0,1,0,1,0])
<filter object at 0x02898690>
callable(a)
False
```

**My Question**: If the filter object isn't callable, then where is it applicable?

Comment: use `None` instead of `"none"`

Comment: Nope. `None` is an object of type `NoneType`, whereas `"none"` is a string of type `str`. Both are distinct from `"None"`.

Comment: that makes complete sense, I guess that was pretty dumb to think that they were equal obviously they arent

Comment: Python has a [strong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) typing system, in comparison to, say, javascript. For example, in javascript `1 + "1"` might equal `2`, because the compiler/intepreter would implicitly convert one of the items. In Python, the same code would raise an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

```
"none" != None
```

What the documentation is saying is that if the `function is None`:

```
filter(None, iterable)
```

It assumes that you only want the items in `iterable` for which `bool(item) == True`.

To actually provide a `function` to `filter`, it is common to use `lambda`:

```
filter(lambda x: x > 5, iterable)
```

or define a function:

```
def some_func(x):
    return x > 5

filter(some_func, iterable)
```

The `filter` object isn't callable, but it is iterable:

```
a = filter(None, iterable)
for item in a:
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

Example usage:

```
>>> list(filter(None, [0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, "", 6, [], 7, 8]))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> def is_multiple_of_two_or_three(x):
        return x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0
>>> list(filter(is_multiple_of_two_or_three, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

With the `lambda` keyword, we could write that as `list(filter(lambda x: x%3 == 0 or x%2 == 0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))`.

In Python 2.x we would get the same results if we removed the call to `list`. In Python 3.x, we could iterate through a filter object without it with `for i in filter(None, something)`, but I put in a call to `list` to show the results (the string representation of an iterable isn't usually that helpful).

The function `filter` is one of the parts of Python (along with `map`, `reduce` and the `functools` and `itertools` modules) that are part of the programming paradigm of [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Function can be any python function:

`def` based function:

```
def func(x):
    return x != 0

>>> list(filter(func, [1,0,1,0,1,0]))
[1, 1, 1]
```

`lambda`:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, [1,0,1,0,1,0]))
[1, 1, 1]
```

And in Python3 `filter` returns an iterator. It never returns a callable.

Comment: `filter` never returns a callable.